# What do you do with a question where the exact technology is not clear and it is relevant for the answer?

Tags: discussion

If a question doesn't specify with what framework the OP is working, and there are, lets say at least two suitable options and both options would require different approaches, what do you do? I mean beyond asking the OP to clarify?

What is the recommended approach? Do I flag the question as "Unclear what you are asking"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, when it's unclear what a question is asking, you vote/flag to close it as "Unclear what you are asking".  You can also comment if you can provide more specific information to the author on what information their question is missing and what they need to provide in order for their question to be acceptable. 
 You can also cast a downvote to reflect the fact that a question is not clear. 
 If/when the question has been edited to provide enough information to be answered, it can be reopened.

Comment: When you state it that way, it seems so silly! But otherwise I could perfectly understand the question, just couldn't provide an answer until I knew the technology being used.  Also many asked the OP but he wouldn't answer, so I was unsure. Thanks!